# Object Prototyping not working in Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, canvas, prototype-programming

So I'm writing a silly little canvas game, mainly a copy of Asteroids. Anyway, I have my button listener set up so that when the user presses the spacebar, the player object's `fire()` function is called:

```
eGi.prototype.keyDownListener = function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 32:
            player.fire();
            break;
```

In the fire function, my script checks if the process is already running, and if not, then it creates a new "bullet" object, stores it in a temporary variable, and adds it to a draw stack.

```
fire:(function() {
    if (this.notFiring) {
        var blankObject = new bullet(this.x,this.y,this.rot,"bullet");
        objects.push(blankObject);
        timer2 = setTimeout((function() {
            objects.pop();
        }),1000);
        this.notFiring = false;
    }}),
```

(By the way, when the user releases the spacebar, `this.notFiring` is set back to true.)

This is the bullet object constructor and its required and prototyped method, `draw(context)`:

```
var bullet = function(x,y,rot,name) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sx = 0;
    this.sy = 0;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.maxSpeed = 10;
    this.rot = rot;
    this.life = 1;
    this.sprite = b_sprite;
    this.name = name;
}
bullet.prototype.draw = function(context) {
    this.sx += this.speed * Math.sin(toRadians(this.rot));
    this.sy += this.speed * Math.cos(toRadians(this.rot));
    this.x += this.sx;
    this.y -= this.sy;
    var cSpeed = Math.sqrt((this.sx*this.sx) + (this.sy * this.sy));
    if (cSpeed > this.maxSpeed) {
        this.sx *= this.maxSpeed/cSpeed;
        this.sy *= this.maxSpeed/cSpeed;    
    }
    context.drawImage(this.sprite,this.x,this.y);
}
```

Anyway, when i run my game and press the spacebar, the Chrome developer console gives me an error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (x,y,rot,name) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sx = 0;
    this.sy = 0;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.maxSpeed = 10;
    this.rot = rot;
    this.life = 1;
    this.sprite = b_sprite;
    this.name = name;
} has no method 'draw'
```

even though i prototyped it. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

after changing `var bullet = function` to `function bullet` and changing `bullet.prototype.draw` to `bullet.draw`, I still get an error. This time, it's more mysterious, saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: type error
    bullet.draw
    (anonymous function)
    eGi.drawObjs
    eGi.cycle
```

the full code is up on my website, [here](http://somekidwithhtml.webs.com/games/asteroids/index.html)

ANOTHER EDIT:

The Chrome console says that this type error occurs on line 122, which happens to be the snippet of code:

```
context.drawImage(this.sprite,this.x,this.y);
```

however, i'm not sure how there could be a type error there, the sprite is an Image, and the X and Y values are not undefined, they are numbers.

Comment: Are you certain that `this.sprite` is defined at the time you pass it to `context.drawImage`?  Try adding `console.log(this.sprite)` to check that first.  Is `b_sprite` defined correctly?

Comment: yes, it's being passed. and i've defined all my sprites in the format
`var b_sprite = new Image();
b_sprite.src = "bullet.png";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling your draw function? I'm betting you're calling `bullet.draw();` instead of calling it on an actual bullet instance.

Kinda like the difference between

```
Cat.meow();
```

and

```
var mittens = new Cat();
mittens.meow();
```

Comment: this is basically correct, the crappy way in which my "engine" (eGi) was executing the draw function was using the "name" i was passing to it, which in this instance happened to be bullet, the same as the class name. I've been working with Objective-C too much, the bullet has to be global for my "engine" to recognize it.